# How to trigger blazor layout method from a page?

Tags: blazor-server-side

I have simplest razor-server app which is created by default when you create a new solution.
I am looking for solution to set a parameter in my layout from my page without using a JS.
And here is the MainLayout:

```
@nherits LayoutComponentBase
    <div class="page @deviceCssClass">
      <div><h3><@Title</h3></div>
      <div class="content px-4">
                @Body
       </div>
     </div>

    @code
    {
        [Parameter]
         public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my App.razor which implements routing for my pages:

App.razor:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <RouteView  RouteData="@routeData"  DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

And here is my page using MainLayout:

Login.razor:

```
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <a href="Identity/Account/Manage">Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!</a>
        <a href="" vclass="nav-link btn btn-link" @onclick="(() => Logout())">Log out</a>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="/Account/Register">Register</a>
        <a href="/Account/Login">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

**Question:**
In my MainLayout I have `@Title` property. This layout is used by many pages. 
How do I set @Title of my layout from a page? Let's sey from Login.razor page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved it using this answer:
[Call method in MainLayout from a page component in Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123063/call-method-in-mainlayout-from-a-page-component-in-blazor)

MainLayout:

```
    <CascadingValue Value=SetTitleEvent>
                        @Body
       </CascadingValue>
 ...
 ...
        @code {
             public EventCallback<string> SetTitleEvent => EventCallback.Factory.Create<string>(this, SetTitle);

             public void SetTitle(string t)
             {
                 Title = t;
              }
        }
```

And razor page:

```
[CascadingParameter]
        protected EventCallback<string> SetTitleEvent { get; set; }

        protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        {
            if (firstRender)
                SetTitleEvent.InvokeAsync("Login");

            return base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
        }
```