# Blazor: Problem on Update the Layout from Page

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I want to access the MainLayout from Pages, to update a value that show the number of items on basket.

To do this, I implement 2 different scenario's:

1. Create Cascade Parameter for Event to call MainLayout Method, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123063/call-method-in-mainlayout-from-a-page-component-in-blazor) thread
2. Cascase Parameter for MainLayout to call public method of them (GetOrderCount)

Both scenario not working properly. Check the sample code:

```cs
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine($"OnAfterRender: {basketNo}");
}

protected override bool ShouldRender()
{
    if (forceRerender)
    {
        forceRerender = false;
        return true;
    }
    return base.ShouldRender();
}

public async Task GetOrderCount()
{
    basketNo = await BasketService.GetCountOrdersAsync();
    await Task.Delay(1);
    forceRerender = true;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

```html
<div class="basket">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-light text-dark pos-relative" href="/Order">
        <i class="bi-basket-fill"></i>
        @if (basketNo > 0)
        {
            <span class="pos-absolute translate-middle badge rounded-pill @ccss">
                @basketNo
            </span>
        }
    </a>
</div>
```

On the Page, after add item to the basket, I call the GetOrderCount method from MainLayout to update the basketNo. everything will run ok and not have any issue. OnAfterRender call after basketNo Changed. but the data on the UI not changed!

On other hand, if i call the method from MainLayout such a @onclick of button, its work and basketNo updated on UI.
I don't know what's the different from Calling from Page or Calling from on MainLayout!?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are showing the basket count in your MainLayout?

Code a `BasketUpdated` event into `BasketService`

```
public event EventHandler BasketUpdated;
```

and invoke the event whenever the basket is updated.

```
this.BasketUpdated?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Add a Basket Count property into `BasketService` linked to the `BasketItems` list.

```
public int BasketCount => this.BasketItems.Count;
```

Create a small component for whatever markup represents the basket in the header.  Lets call it `BasketCountComponent`.  Inject the `BasketService` into `BasketCountComponent`.  Register an event handler in `BasketCountComponent` wired to `BasketService.BasketUpdated`.  Link the markup in `BasketCountComponent` directly to the injected `BasketService.BasketCount' property.

The component should look something like this:

```
@implements IDisposable

<div>BasketCount : @basketService.BasketCount</div>

@code {
[Inject] private BasketService basketService {get; set;}

protected void OnInitialized()
  => basketService.BasketChanged += this.OnBasketChanged;

private void OnBasketChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  => StateHasChanged();

public void Dispose()
  => basketService.BasketChanged -= this.OnBasketChanged;
}
```

If you want to see a working version of something similar look at my [Notification Service Demo Repo on Github](https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.DBNotification)

PS I haven't actually run this code so there may be some typos!

Comment: Hi buddy, Thanks for sharing a innovative solution. its work perfectly.

Comment: If it works perfectly well, then please accept the answer.