# System.InvalidOperationException: 'The render handle is not yet assigned.' in Blazor server

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I have created a simple Blazor application and I need to show a loading screen on the index.razor page. I am not needed to include it on the index.razor page. I am using some indirect way to do it.

First I have created a one class called Appsettings.cs and brought the loading logic inside it

**Appsettings.cs**

```
public class AppSettings
    {
        public static bool _IsProcessing { get; set; } = false;

        public static MainLayout _layout { get; set; } = new MainLayout();

        public static void Loading(bool isProcessing)
        {
            _IsProcessing = isProcessing;

            if(_layout !=null)
               _layout .LoadingScreenShowing(_IsProcessing);
        }

    }
```

Then my index.razor file is like this, when press the below Load button, I need to show the Loading screen.

**index.razor**

```
<button onclick="PageLoading">Load</button>
@code{
  protected override void Oninitialized(){}

  private void PageLoading(){
     AppSettings.Loading(true);
     this.StateHasChanged();
     //do something
     AppSettings.Loading(false);
     this.StateHasChanged();
         
  }
```

After I have included loading part into the MainLayout.razor not explicitly to the index.razor.

**MainLayout.razor**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<PageTitle>BlazorApp1</PageTitle>

<div class="page">
<div class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu />
</div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            <Loading IsVisible="@IsLoading" @ref="load"/>  //loading component 
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
```

And I've created a partial class to place the functional part of the main layout.

MainLayout.razor.cs

```
public partial class MainLayout{
        private bool IsLoading;
        Loading load ;

        public async void LoadingScreenShowing(bool isLoading)
        {
            load = new Loading();
            IsLoading = isLoading;
            this.StateHasChanged();//exception is throwing from this line 
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
}
```

When execute the this.StateHasChanged() line, I am getting the exception called

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The render handle is not yet
> assigned.'

Why is this occurring?

Comment: I believe this is because `_layout` in `AppSettings` is not the same instance than the one used in index.razor. `AppSettings._layout` is not actually rendered anywhere.

Comment: T.Trassoudaine thanks for your comment, then do you have any suggestions to be done ??

Comment: I don't think trying to make `_layout` static is a good idea, even if you succeed to bind it to the right instance. You could define your `AppSettings` methods in `MainLayout` and call them from the components. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123063/call-method-in-mainlayout-from-a-page-component-in-blazor) could help you with this.

Comment: Indeed, avoid `static` and `async` void as much as you can. You don't  `new()` Blazor components or layouts. Blazor does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it the way your are trying to.  Component lifecycles are managed by the Renderer: you can't create a component instance and somehow shoehorn it into a page.  That's the reason for the error.

Here's a heavily refactored version of your code that I think does what intend.

The scoped service that maintains the App State (your `AppSettings`):

```
public class AppStateService
{
    private bool _isLoaded;

    public event Action? LoadStateChanged;

    public bool IsLoaded
    {
        get => _isLoaded;
        set
        {
            if (_isLoaded != value)
            {
                _isLoaded = value;
                LoadStateChanged?.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

registered in program:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<AppStateService>();
```

The Loading component - I've used a simple bootstrap alert to display the loading message.

```
@inject AppStateService appStateService
@implements IDisposable

@if (!this.appStateService.IsLoaded)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        Page Loading...
    </div>
}

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
        => this.appStateService.LoadStateChanged += this.OnStateChanged;

    private void OnStateChanged()
        => this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

    public void Dispose()
        => this.appStateService.LoadStateChanged -= this.OnStateChanged;
}
```

MainLayout:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<PageTitle>BlazorApp3</PageTitle>

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4 auth">
            <LoginDisplay />
            <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            <Loading />
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
```

And finally the demo page:

```
@page "/"
@inject AppStateService appStateService; 

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@code{

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        this.appStateService.IsLoaded = false;
        // emulate an async loading event 
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        this.appStateService.IsLoaded = true;
    }
}
```